# Connection can´t be started

Tags: c#

I have an error that i can't fix.

```
 SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=
                 (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=
                  C:\Users\gpsi1_000\Desktop\Pap 
                  Fábio\db\clientes.mdf;Integrated Security=True;
                  Connect Timeout=30");
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

This is how i connect to database:

```
if (txtnovocp.Text != "" & txtnovamora.Text != "" 
               & txtnovaloca.Text != "" & txtnovoconce.Text != "")
 {
    cn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Postal   
                     (Codigo_Postal,Morada,Localidade,Concelho) 
                     VALUES('" + txtnovocp.Text + "','" +
                     txtnovamora.Text + "', '" + txtnovaloca.Text 
                      + "' , '" + txtnovoconce.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Clone();
    MessageBox.Show("Código-Postal Inserido");
    cn.Close();
    txtnovocp.Text = "";
    txtnovaloca.Text = "";
    txtnovamora.Text = "";
    txtnovoconce.Text = "";
  }
```

And this is my code to insert in Postal

but when i click on button to save the values show me an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' 
occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: 
A propriedade Connection não foi inicializada.
```

Comment: Likely you are not passing `cn` to `cmd` anywhere? In its constructor for example? - Also you need to parametrize that as its vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: if i put cn in all lines show me an error

Comment: An SqlCommand need to know what connection should use to reach the database. You need to set the Connection property of the command or better use the appropriate constructor

Comment: Perhaps with a little effort you could take a look at the examples of MSDN? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: here's a basic example (easy to find by googling slqcommand) http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection

Comment: possible duplicate of [ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Answer (score 1):

In english the error message is:

> Additional information: ExecuteNonQuery: The Connection property is
>   not initialized.

I find it very meaningful, isn't it? You have to initialize the connection and assign it to the command.

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\gpsi1_000\Desktop\Pap Fábio\db\clientes.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cn;  // <-----
```

If this is a member of the class you cannot assign the connection to the command inline. Normally you use the costructor of the class.

```
SqlConnection cn = null;
SqlCommand cmd = null;

public ClassName()
{
    cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\gpsi1_000\Desktop\Pap Fábio\db\clientes.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
}
```

Comment: Error 2 Invalid token ';' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: Error 1 Invalid token '=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: There's also [CreateCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so `SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand()`, no need to assign the connection in that case.

Comment: @BrunoGonçalves: if that are fields in your class use the constructor, shown an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
using (var connection =  new SqlConnection...)
{
    connection.Open();
    var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    ...
}
```