# dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I am using dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); in my program, but when I run my program I receive this 
**error message:**

> executenonquery connection property has not been initialized

What should I do?

Comment: Without your code it's getting hard to find some useful tips. Maybe you forgot to set the connection attribute? Take a Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Comment: [`dbCommand.Connection = yourConnection;`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.connection(v=vs.110).aspx) solved

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Connection` property on your `dbCommand` object. It's possible to create a command object from your connection using something like

```
SqlCommand dbCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
```

Alternatively, some DbCommand` constructor overloads allow you to specify the connection. For example...

```
SqlCommand dbCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from * where * = *", connection);
```

Also, make sure you have opened your connection - `connection.Open();`