# Read a sql query with C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldatareader, fusioncharts

I tried to get my sql query read, but it does not really work. It is all working until it comes to the query part and then on the line:

```
rst = query.ExecuteReader();
```

It gets an error:

> Connection property has not been initialized.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

```
 Chart chart = new Chart();
    StringBuilder xmlStr = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder strCategories = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder strProcesses = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder strTasks = new StringBuilder();

    xmlStr.Append("<chart logoURL='../../Images/Piktogramme/" + chart.Image + "' caption='" + chart.Caption + "' theme='flat'" + " dateformat='dd/mm/yyyy' showTaskLabels='1'>"); // attributes will go here

    // Category for each month
    for (int i = -12; i < 6; i++)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        today = today.AddMonths(i);
        strCategories.Append("<category start='1/" + today.Month + "/" + today.Year + "' end='" + DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month) + "/" + today.Month + "/" + today.Year + "' name='" + today.ToString("MMM") + "' />");
    }

    // Get the connection string
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CRM_SQL"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        // Establish the connection with the database
        conn.Open();

        // Construct and execute SQL query which would return the total amount of sales for each year
        SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
        // Begin iterating through the result set
        SqlDataReader rst;
        query.CommandText = "SELECT * from table";
        rst = query.ExecuteReader();


        while (rst.Read())
        {
            // Construct the chart data in XML format
            strProcesses.AppendFormat("<process name='{1}' id='{0}' />", rst[0], rst[1]);
            strTasks.AppendFormat("<task name='{0}' processid='{1}' start='{2}' end='{3}' />", rst[4], rst[0], rst[2], rst[3]);
        }
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        xmlStr.Append("<trendlines><line start='" + DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month) + "/" + today.Month + "/" + today.Year + "' displayvalue='Heute'/></trendlines>");
        // End the XML string
        xmlStr.Append("<categories>" + strCategories.ToString() + "</categories> <processes>" + strProcesses.ToString() + "</processes> <tasks width='10'>" + strTasks.ToString() + "</tasks> </chart>");

        // Close the result set Reader object and the Connection object
        rst.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

    return xmlStr.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Same question and problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `SqlCommand` object has no link to your `SqlConnection`.

Replace the line:

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
```

By:

```
SqlCommand query = conn.CreateCommand();
```

PS: Like `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are also disposable, so you can/should also use `using`.
And the line `conn.Close();` is useless because `using` will take care of it.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this;

```
var  query  = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from table", conn);
```

another way is assigning the connection string

```
query.connection = conn;
```

Answer (score 3):

Add following

```
query.Connection=conn;
```

after

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    // Establish the connection with the database
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from table", conn))
    {
        query.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (var rst = query.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rst.Read())
            {
                strProcesses.AppendFormat("<process name='{1}' id='{0}' />", rst[0], rst[1]);
                strTasks.AppendFormat("<task name='{0}' processid='{1}' start='{2}' end='{3}' />", rst[4], rst[0], rst[2], rst[3]);
            }
        }
    }
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
    xmlStr.Append("<trendlines><line start='" + DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month) + "/" + today.Month + "/" + today.Year + "' displayvalue='Heute'/></trendlines>");
    // End the XML string
    xmlStr.Append("<categories>" + strCategories.ToString() + "</categories> <processes>" + strProcesses.ToString() + "</processes> <tasks width='10'>" + strTasks.ToString() + "</tasks> </chart>");
    conn.Close();
}
```