# SQL ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql, executenonquery

I'm trying to figure out how to save to db an image. I wrote the following code, but I keep getting this error on line 51, which is cmd.ExecuteNonQuery;. I can't figure out why. The connection ("conn") is already opened before it, but still shows the error. Thanks !

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (numeTextBox.TextLength != 0 || prenumeTextBox.TextLength != 0)
                {
                    var connString = (@"Data Source= |DataDirectory|\Angajati.sdf");

                    using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            conn.Open();
                            SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
                            SqlCeParameter picture = new SqlCeParameter("@picture", SqlDbType.Image);
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
                            byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
                            ms.Close();
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@picture", a);
                            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO info(Nume, Prenume,Data, Proiect, Schimburi, Poza) VALUES('" + numeTextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + prenumeTextBox.Text.Trim() + "', '" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "', '" + textBox1.Text.Trim() + "', '" + radioButton1.Text + "', @picture);";
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            conn.Close();
                            MessageBox.Show("Salvat cu succes!");
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                        }

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Trebuie sa completezi campurile inainte de a salva!");
                }
            }
```

Comment: `cmd.Connection = conn;`. But use sql-parameters.

Comment: And now it says that "The data was truncated while converting from one data type to another". Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized

Comment: follow Tim suggestion , "data was truncated" error is due to VALUES settings error (bad data type) for example Nume and PreNume are char or numeric ?

Comment: The types are alright. Maybe the problem is at the last, picture, because it is setted as image type. Shouldn't have this type?

Comment: how is it defined in your database table ?

Comment: Which? picture? as image type.

Comment: try replacing this "byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();" with "byte[] a = ms.ToArray();"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87772/discussion-between-user3348368-and-luca).