# ExecuteScalar has not been initialized

Tags: c#

I keep getting this error saying that `"ExecuteScalar has not been initialized"` I have new to C# but had a look through google and tutorials and still cant see what the problem is. Its probably a very silly mistake but if anyone could help. Thanks :)

```
           // open connection 
           myConnection.Open();


           // sql command 
           string Account_Num = txt_acc.Text;
           string Pin_num = txt_pin.Text;


           SqlCommand check_details = new SqlCommand("select Account_num, Pin_num from Cust_details where Account_num='" + txt_acc.Text + "'and Pin_num ='" + txt_pin.Text + "'"); 
           check_details.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_num", txt_acc.Text);
           check_details.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pin_num", txt_pin.Text);


           int result = Convert.ToInt32(check_details.ExecuteScalar());

           if (result > 0)
           {
               Console.WriteLine("user exists");
           }


           else
           {
               Console.WriteLine("error");
           }
       }
```

Comment: Maybe if you'd have searched the web for the _actual_ exception you'd have found the [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized). :)

Comment: You need to give connection name to your command. Also why you are adding acco_num and pin_num in query when you add them in parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you didn't connect your command with connection. Just set it's [`Connection` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx) to `myConnection`.

```
check_details.Connection = myConnection;
```

or you can set it on your `SqlCommand` constructor as a second parameter;

```
SqlCommand check_details = new SqlCommand("yourCommand", myConnection);
```

or you can use [`CreateCommand` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.createcommand.aspx) from your connection;

```
SqlCommand check_details = myConnection.CreateCommand();
```

And you are misunderstood the [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death). You *still* do string concatenation in your sql query but you try to add parameters. That's meaningless.

Use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your connection and command automatically as well.

Also don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.

```
using(var myConnection = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var check_details = myConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    check_details.CommandText = @"select Account_num, Pin_num from Cust_details 
                                  where Account_num = @accnum
                                  and Pin_num = @pinnum";
    // I assume your column types as Int
    check_details.Parameters.Add("@accnum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(txt_acc.Tex);
    check_details.Parameters.Add("@pinnum", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(txt_pin.Text);
    myConnection.Open();
    int result = (int)check_details.ExecuteScalar();
    ...
}
```

By the way, there is no point to select `Pin_num` column in your command since `ExecuteScalar` ignores it.