# exception error "ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized." this is my C# Coding

Tags: c#, sqlcommand

I am trying to execute a query to delete a book record from my database given an ID. When I click the delete button, I get the following error:

> ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

My code so far is:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)//delete book
{
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [tbl_Book] WHERE Book_ID='"+txtBookID.Text+"'");
    cn.Open();
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Book Deleted Successfully", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);                
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize new `sql connection` and pass it to `Sql command object`.

```
   private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         Sqlconection connection = new Sqlconection("Your Connection String Here");
         connection.Open();
         SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [tbl_Book] WHERE Book_ID='"+txtBookID.Text+"'", connection);
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
         connection.Close();
         MessageBox.Show("Book Deleted Successfully", "System", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
   }
```

Hopes this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You did not bind the `command with connection`. You can do it right in constructor.

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Your Query", connection);
```