# ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized. c sharo

Tags: c#, sql, .net

**may be i am tired but any body can say what is the poblem?**

```
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename='c:\users\deltagare\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\School\School\school.mdf';Integrated Security=True");
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'schoolDataSet.student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        //this.studentTableAdapter.Fill(this.schoolDataSet.student);

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from student";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        student = new StudentController();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

         da.Fill(dt);

        studentGridView.DataSource = dt;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Answer (score 3):

You have either to use the [`SqlCommand(string,SqlConnection)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/877h0y3a(v=vs.110).aspx) overload, or set the [SqlCommand.Connection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from student",conn);
```

Or

```
cmd.Connection=conn;
```

Comment: As my answer explains, you haven't set the `Connection` property of  your `SqlCommand`. What don't you understand of it?

Answer (score 0):

you have to assign the connection to the command before you execute it:

```
cmd.Connection = conn
```