# InvalidOperationException: Connection property has not been initialized in update command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Students set RegNo='" + RegNo.Text + "',Name='" + Name.Text + "',Address=" + Address.Text);
    con.Open();
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "javascript:alert('Record Updated Successfully');", true);    
        Response.Write("Record saved successfully");
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx"); 
}
```

This code displays an error like this:

> System.InvalidOperationException. ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Comment: How to solve this error. Really i don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I think , in the SQL Command you need to assign the connection

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Students set RegNo='" + RegNo.Text + "',Name='" + Name.Text + "',Address=" + Address.Text);
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (result == 1)
    {
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "javascript:alert('Record Updated Successfully');", true);    
        Response.Write("Record saved successfully");
    }
    Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your sql command that use this connection(con)  to execute the command(cmd).so use an overloaded constructor of the SqlCommand class that takes 2 parameters(cmdText, connection).

```
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Students set RegNo='" +
     RegNo"',Name='" + Name.Text + "',Address=" + Address.text, con);
```

But it is also possible, to create an instance of SqlCommand class using the parameter less constructor, and then later specify the command text and connection, using the CommandText and Connection properties of the SqlCommand object as shown below.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Students set RegNo='" + RegNo.Text + "',Name='" + Name.Text + "',Address=" + Address.Text);
 cmd.Connection = con;
 con.Open();
```

You can use the using statement where the resources are automatically disposed.We don't have to explicitly call Close() method, when using is used. The connection will be automatically closed for us.

```
         int result;
          using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Students set RegNo='" + RegNo.Text + "',Name='" + Name.Text + "',Address=" + Address.Text, con);
                con.Open();
                result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 } 
                if (result == 1)
                {
                    //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ShowSuccess", "javascript:alert('Record Updated Successfully');", true);    
                    Response.Write("Record saved successfully");
                }
                Response.Redirect("~/WebForm1.aspx");
```

Answer (score 0):

To try to use as following sample code

```
string constr ="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=test;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=1111"
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update Student set Name='" + Name.Text + "',Address='" + Address.Text + "'where RegNo=" + RegNo.Text);

            cmd.Connection = con;//adding this line my error solved
            con.Open();
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

I changed my code like above.