# Getting the following "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.'"

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.'" error while running the following code.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"String_data");
public student_info()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string insert = "INSERT INTO Table VALUES('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully");
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the line. As you are only providing SQL Command and not providing connection i.e., server name, database name, user id and password.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insert);
```

To

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(con, insert);
```

You can learn here in [**SqlCommand Class**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: When I did, I'm getting the following error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.'

Comment: Yes, the table's name is 'Table'. What might be the issue?

Comment: Change INSERT INTO Table VALUES to INSERT INTO [Table] VALUES or I suggest you to change the name of table with other name.

Comment: Worked! Adding the box brackets solved it! Just to know, how do I change the table's name? I tried it in the table's properties but couldn't.