# Getting "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.'"

Tags: c#

I am working on a SQL connection through C# but on the `sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line, when I run it and put information into the form it does not work. Crashing and giving me the error, the code for my program follows. Also include a screenshot of the form. I have been trying to fix this for a while but no luck, tried switching the code around and more but generally just didn't work. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpFGj.png

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace WindowsFormApp32
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-SQ1V840;Initial Catalog=UserRegistration;Integrated Security=True";


        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }




        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                if (textBox5.Text + textBox6.Text == " ")
                    MessageBox.Show("Please fill mandatory fields");

                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserAdd");
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", textBox1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", textBox2.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_ID", textBox3.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", textBox4.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", richTextBox1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton2.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", comboBox1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox5.Text.Trim());

                using (var connectionString = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-SQ1V840;Initial Catalog=UserRegistration;Integrated Security=True"))
                using (var cmd = new SqlDataAdapter())
                using (var insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Application VALUES (@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Email_ID, @Contact, @Address, @Gender, @Department, @Username, @Password) "))
                {
                    insertCommand.Connection = connectionString;
                    cmd.InsertCommand = insertCommand;

                    connectionString.Open();

                }
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    MessageBox.Show("Registration successful");
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I've fixed it up a little but it's still giving me a error for "sqlCmd.Connection = connectionString;" giving me a error on the connectionString part

The code shows following now

````
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserAdd");
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", textBox1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", textBox2.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_ID", textBox3.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", textBox4.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", richTextBox1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton2.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", comboBox1.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox5.Text.Trim());
                sqlCmd.Connection = connectionString;```
````

Comment: You didn't set `sqlCmd.Connection`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263094/executenonquery-connection-property-has-not-been-initialized

Comment: Your code doesn't need to use `SqlDataAdapter` either - I would stick with straight `SqlCommand`. And  / or read up on Dapper.

Comment: Why are you passing `Gender` twice?

Comment: You have already opened a connection and then again initialized another connection object which does not contain `.open()` method. It is pretty straightforward why you are getting the initialization error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add some code twice, it's redundant ... 
So you have to do only this:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-SQ1V840;Initial Catalog=UserRegistration;Integrated Security=True";


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                if (textBox5.Text.Trim() + textBox6.Text.Trim() == "")
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show("Please fill mandatory fields");
                     return;
                 }

                sqlCon.Open();
                using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("UserAdd", sqlCon)) // you missed to pass connection to command
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", textBox1.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", textBox2.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email_ID", textBox3.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact", textBox4.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", richTextBox1.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", radioButton1.Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", comboBox1.Text.Trim()); // also I think here must be comboBox1.SelectedValue, not Text property
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", textBox5.Text.Trim());

                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Registration successful");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show($"Error on SQL \"UserAdd\" procedure: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes... my mistake, I did it without VS opened, and I did not see the {} block correctly in editor. Sorry!

Comment: Also, I have removed @Gendre parameter sent twice, with both `RadioButton`s

Comment: I've put this code in but it gives me a error CS0136 on line 64 where "catch (Exception e)" comes in

Comment: Change `e` to `ex`.

Comment: So everything works properly, the only problem now is just the Gender radioboxes, since it was removed, only male works I tried playing around it but it didnt work, is there anyway around this?

Comment: `radioButton1.Checked ? 'male' : 'female'`... or something like that, depending on your `RadioButton`s text...

Comment: But I think, also, there are some parameters in your SP that must be ID's not texts. So, the database must be normalized better... So, you must consider Gendre could be displayed in a `ComboBox`, with the value of ID's from "Gendre Table", `@Department` must be `@DepartmentID` which must be an `integer`, or whatever do you want to store yours IDs in tables. And so on.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing u everything here. You need to run the respective command in the respective connection. this line is also wrong `connectionString.Open();` Also you have not provided `Connection` to `sqlCmd`.